# Requested operation requires an OLE DB Session object, which is not supported by the current provider

Tags: sql-server, vbscript

Iam asking question there are previous 2 same posts but none of them worked for my code, so iam putting question here

```vb
Function getJobHistory1(ByVal ServerName)   
  Set cmdsrvlist1 = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
  Set cnsrvlist1  = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
  Set rssrvlist1  = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  MsgBox(ServerName)

  'tried the following; not working
  'cnsrvlist.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source=Av-RISCDCSQL821\SQL821;Integrated Security=SSPI"

  'tried this as well; not working
  cnsrvlist1.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Data Source=" & ServerName & ";Integrated Security=SSPI"
  MsgBox(cnsrvlist1)
  cnsrvlist1.Open 

  cmdsrvlist1.ActiveConnection = cnsrvlist1

  cn.Close
End Function
```

Getting the following error:

[image: Requested operation requires an OLE DB Session object, which is not supported by the current provider.]

Comment: Did you try to first set the connection string and then open it, then process and then close?

Comment: thats wht  i have done in code

Comment: The example shows that you first open it then set it. You are trying to open an undefined connection doing it that way.

Comment: tht open is commented in vbscript i have just written tht code to show tht i have tried that oledb provider as well

Comment: Do this in code: 1 Declare variable. 2. Set variable to new object. 3 Set connection (connection string). 4 Open connection 5. Process. 6. Close connection. Let me know if you need an example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133526/discussion-between-danie-schoeman-and-deepti).

Comment: can anybody please help me

Comment: What's `cn.Close` meant to be? Plus why try two different ways of setting the connection string but switch the provider? How do you expect to do a like for like test if you move the goal posts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Requested operation requires an OLE DB Session object... - Connecting Excel to SQL server via ADO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669777/requested-operation-requires-an-ole-db-session-object-connecting-excel-to-s)