# VB 6.0 to Sql 2014 connection, Getting error Requested operation requires an OLE DB Session object, which is not supported by the current provider

Tags: sql, vb6, connection, connection-string, sql-server-2014

From VB 6.0 to Sql 2014 connection, getting below error: while opening a connection getting below error:
code where error thrown : SQLConnectionObjct.Open(ConnectionStringValue)

Exception Message :
Getting error Requested operation requires an OLE DB Session object, which is not supported by the current provider.

Something wrong with database connection string, not able to figure it out.

Comment: The error message is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/41736746, but no answer is offered yet.

Comment: What type of vb object(s) are you using (ADODB?)?  What provider are you using?  What is the contents of your connection string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Requested operation requires an OLE DB Session object... - Connecting Excel to SQL server via ADO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669777/requested-operation-requires-an-ole-db-session-object-connecting-excel-to-s)

Comment: yes, ADODB.Connection
Connection String : Driver={SQL Server};Server=ServerName;Database=DBName;Trusted_Connection=Yes;
ODBC Onnection : using the SQLSRV32.DLL

Comment: Since the error message mentions OLE DB, have you tried the MS OLEDB provider?  See https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/#microsoft-ole-db-provider-for-sql-server-sqloledb.

Comment: Yes tried using Provider=sqloledb; But no luck